# How can I take an object, set it to a specific property that is from a predetermined value that matches a property from another object?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

*** I revised the above question so that it would make more sense based upon the intention of my question and the confusion / missunderstanding one might occur from this code pattern.

What I am trying to accomplish in overall terms is the ability to create an object, from being empty, and set it to something that has a property name and at the same time is setting that property name to a value of another object.

What this will allow me to do is create an object that will have a property that will contain an object that has propert(ies) which one of them will be the key, value of which that value will be the name of the property in which the new object is set to.

Why would I need this or want this new object...

The purpose of this pattern, unto which i see the use for is to obtain an object that is set to an interface/name in which the object that is set to the containing property is of the same name to one of the values in the referenced property's value.  It sounds confusing so i created a jsbin to illustrate a solution to exactly what I am asking for... If someone else has a better explanation or title for what my question is please advise.

The answer I provide along with code sample is what I am asking and achieving through my understanding.

------PREVIOUS QUESTION--------

The question i have is why or when should one decide to take an objects property and set it to another object. For me, it seems like inheritence "setting" is the reason but I am not 100% sure.  Furthermore, I am not sure when i should think of this and in what situations I should decide to use such a pattern.

I can read the code and follow it but the most confusion I have and question relating to is specifically the object[property] = otherObject;

Perhaps this has to do with the Object.assign() construction? What I do know is I have seen this done a few times and a little confused to as why and when i should know to use such a pattern.  Still, there may be something else I am missing here.

Here is the code example I am referencing.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  completedAssets : 0,
  totalAssets : 0,
  currentDownloads: {},
  logs: []
};
}

let currDownloadObject = {
  fileName: fileName,
  currentSize: loaded,
  totalSize: total,
  complete: (loaded === total),
  completeOrder : fileCompleteOrder,
  order: (file) ? file.order : Object.keys(this.state.currentDownloads).length + 1
}

let currentDownloadStateArray = Object.assign({},this.state.currentDownloads);

currentDownloadStateArray[fileName] = currDownloadObject;

this.setState({currentDownloads: currentDownloadStateArray});
```

Here is an example of the output that is the most confusing for me.

when running this log statement:

```
console.log('currentDownloadStateArray ', currentDownloadStateArray);
```

I get this example of a return:

```
https://navigation/az.png: {fileName: "https://navigation/az.png", currentSize: 7451, totalSize: 7451, complete: true, completeOrder: 1, …}
https://navigation/destination.png: {fileName: "https://avigation/destination.png", currentSize: 8322, totalSize: 8322, complete: true, completeOrder: 2, …}
```

So now, in effect, currentDownloadStateArray is set to an object with an interface of each of it's fileName's property.  <<< Why is this happening and what is it used for

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: What exactly confuses you? That Objects can be nested? Or this code?

Comment: @JonasWilms I get objects can be nested and dictionary of dictinoary's... What is confusing is that why am I setting the object's property to another object?  So for example, this newObj[property] will equal to someOtherObject... Why would I need to do this... does that make more sense?

Comment: and @JonasWilms then when i finally set the state obj of currentDownloads: i only use the newObj array which is currentDownloads: currentDownloadStateArray... not currentDownloadStateArray[fileName]

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Well apparently the state is holding an object with one download per filename, each file having its own object.

Comment: @SLaks that has nothing to do with what the question is asking.

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you wanting to know the answer to the question in your title? or are you more interested in why it is being done in a specific case? Why it is ever done generally?

Comment: @KevinB I want to know the question in the title but i might be missunderstanding something more general with the current code construction... If that makes any sense.

Comment: What line specifically?

Comment: `why am I setting the object's property to another object? \` probably because you wanna store the object in the dictionary?

Comment: @KevinB these 2 specifically... currentDownloadStateArray[fileName] = currDownloadObject;

this.setState({currentDownloads: currentDownloadStateArray});

why do i need to set it to a specfic property and then call it directly in general...

Comment: That line is part of the process of constructing an object to be passed to setState. That is the purpose of doing so in this case. the object needed said property with said value. There is no deeper meaning to this construct.

Comment: @KevinB in the output of currentdownloadStateArray is the following:

Comment: so what appears to me is that the variable is now transformed into an interface entitled by the properties [fileName] and is now the acutally of the new obj.  That is the confusing part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new object that is set to a value by another object which contains that object you would do the following.

```
let state = {
  iteratedFoo: {} // this is a dictionary of dictionaried objects... an object which is a collection of objects.
};

let currentDownloadState = (someValue, anotherValue, urlName) => {

let bar = {
  fileName: urlName,
  someProp: someValue,
  anotherProp: anotherValue
}

let foo = Object.assign({}, state['iteratedFoo'] )

// console.log('foo[urlName] = ', foo[urlName]); // undefined because it wasn't set yet on first loop

foo[urlName] = bar;

console.log('bar ', bar);
console.log('foo ', foo);
console.log('foo[urlName] = ', foo[urlName]);

state['iteratedFoo'] = foo;

console.log('state["iteratedFoo"] ', state['iteratedFoo']);
}

currentDownloadState('this value', 'another value', 'www.msn.com');
currentDownloadState('this value', 'another value', 'www.espn.com');
currentDownloadState('this value', 'another value', 'www.theverge.com');
```

As this function is repeated the iteratedFoo object creates an object that is a collection of the foo object which contains a property name that contains a value that has properties where one of them is the value of the foo property name... in this case foo[urlName]

http://jsbin.com/linebap/1/edit?js,console

The purpose and usecase for this would ultimately to create a collection of objects that are referneced by a property value of said referenced object.

the resulting state.iteratedFoo object now looks like this...

```
"state[\"iteratedFoo\"] "
[object Object] {
 www.espn.com: [object Object] {
    anotherProp: "another value",
    fileName: "www.espn.com",
    someProp: "this value"
  },
  www.msn.com: [object Object] {
    anotherProp: "another value",
    fileName: "www.msn.com",
    someProp: "this value"
  },
 www.theverge.com: [object Object] {
    anotherProp: "another value",
    fileName: "www.theverge.com",
    someProp: "this value"
  }
}
```